# How can I make it easier to move files from an underprivileged (user) account to a root directory in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I'm sure it's been asked and answered many times, but I can't seem to find an answer.  Maybe this question will link someone else to the right answer.

Here's the problem:

> ~$ sudo ls
>   
>   ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied

Here's what I want to do:

> ~$ sudo cp synergy.conf /etc

Here's what happens:

> cp: cannot stat `synergy.conf': Permission denied

Here's what I end up doing:

> ~$ cp synergy.conf /tmp
>   
>   ~$ sudo cp /tmp/synergy.conf /etc/

What can I do to make this easier?  Is there a way to give sudo privileges to see my home directory?

Comment: Assuming you're `sudo`-ing to root, why not just use `su -c` when `sudo` hits corner cases?

Comment: is your current directory on a remote machine?

Comment: I am sudo'ing to root.  su -c has the same problem: `$ sudo su -c "mv foo /etc"` yields `mv: cannot open 'foo' for reading: Permission denied`.  My current directory is on a local machine.  Yes.